# How to plot time series data contained in DataFrame for specific days, potentially resulting in a single record

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Is there any way I can create a line chart for a `DataFrame` holding only one record ?

The sample data I have in the `DataFrame`: Head = ['Date','Count1','Count2','Count3']

```
01-10-2010, 100, 0 , 100
```

X Axis: I am trying to display the date on base of every Sunday

Y Axis: All other 3 counts

I have referred to https://python-graph-gallery.com/122-multiple-lines-chart/ but I am trying to find a way how I can create a chart with one record.

Please help me if someone has any sample code.

Comment: What should you chart look like for this data?  A single vertical line?

Comment: @ScottBoston.. Yes scott

Answer (score 1):

Plotting a single record as a line is per definition not possible, since you need two points to define a line space.

However, as I read your question, you want to plot the datapoints you have for a given day of the week as a timeseries.

If this is the case, you could try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

First, let's generate a range of (daily) dates and some random data for your counts:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='01/31/2020', freq='D')
count1 = np.random.randint(0,100,len(dates))
count2 = np.random.randint(0,100,len(dates))
count3 = np.random.randint(0,100,len(dates))
```

This we use to define a pandas dataframe with the dates as index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 'count1': count1, 'count2': count2, 'count3': count3})
df.set_index('dates', inplace=True)
```

If you want to plot the data just for sundays, we can do this with a single line of code (followed by forcing matplotlib to draw):

```
df[df.index.weekday==6].plot()
plt.show()
```

This last expression makes use of the numeric weekday indexing in Pandas' DateTimeIndex, in which mondays == 0, tuesdays == 1, ..., sundays == 6.

This results in the following plot:

[image]

However, line plotting does not work for single data points. If we only have a single datapoint in our dataframe, we have to set the plots `style` property to `'.'`, which corresponds to a scatter plot:

```
df[df.index.weekday==6].plot(style='.')
```

[image]

This then also works for single data points like we would have for a data range of just one week:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='01/07/2020', freq='D')
count1 = np.random.randint(0,100,len(dates))
count2 = np.random.randint(0,100,len(dates))
count3 = np.random.randint(0,100,len(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 'count1': count1, 'count2': count2, 'count3': count3})
df.set_index('dates', inplace=True)
df[df.index.weekday==6].plot(style='.')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.  if the dataframe df has only 1 record will the graph will not be generated ?

Comment: I updated the answer to give you an option for plotting also single records. However, this can only be done as a scatter plot then, and not with a line plot. Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: although i have numerical columns i am getting an error: TypeError: no numeric data to plot. Is there any way i can find

Comment: Can i ask one doubt

Comment: In this answer . Data frame has around 7 records due to np.random genration. But i do have 1 record and i am unable to create scatter plot. If i provided ** pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='01/01/2020', freq='D') , i am getting TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

Answer (score 1):

You need to reshape your dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['01-10-2010',100,0,100]], columns=['Date','Count1','Count2','Count3']

df
```

Output:

```
        Date  Count1  Count2  Count3
0 2010-01-10     100       0     100
```

Set index convert to datetime dtype and reshape using `melt`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df.melt('Date').set_index('Date').plot()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: @ May i know Is there a possibility to get two lines that is for Count1 and Count3 ?

Comment: @Because i am getting complete graph as blank and i am unable to get line

Comment: Check  the dtypes of your data.  make sure they are numbers (int) or (float)

Comment: @May i know Is there a possibility to get two lines that is for Count1 and Count3 ?

Comment: A line requires two points, you have a single point for each count.